# What would an ideal I generated by e.g. 15 and 12 look like? What would the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z} / I$ look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

What would an ideal I generated by e.g. 15 and 12 look like?

What would the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z} / I$ look like? How do I find a formal representation for this quotient ring?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Don't forget to accept an answer if you find that it answers your question well ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $I=(n,m)$ then $I=(gdc(n,m))$. Therefore $I=(15,12)=(3)$ and the quotient is the field $\mathbb{Z}/(3)=\mathbb{Z}_{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is the ideal generated by $\gcd(12,15)$, hence the quotient is
$$\mathbf Z/I=\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z.$$

Comment: Thanks! That was a lot more simple than I expected. However, I don't see how this can be a solution, since the $\mathbb{Z}_3$ contains elements which is not a multiple of 15 or 12? I guess there is just something fundamental that I don't understand.

Comment: Multiples of 15 or of 12 are contained in the set of multiples of 3. It is af though you were grouping classes mod. 15, say , together: $3\mathbf Z$ is the union of the 5 classes mod. 15: $\;15\mathbf Z, 3+15\mathbf Z, 6+15\mathbf Z, 9+15\mathbf Z,12+15\mathbf Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see why the ideal is indeed generated by the gcd.

Recall the definition of a generated ideal. In this case:

$$I = \{ 15m + 12n = 3(5m + 4n) : m,n \in \mathbb {Z}\}$$

Now, by Bezout/Reverse Euclid, since $5$ and $4$ are coprime, we can find $p, q $ st $5p + 4q = 1$ (in this case $p=1, q=-1$ will do) and hence $5pr+4qr = r $ for any $r \in \mathbb {Z} $.

Hence everything of the form $3r $ is in $I$, and you can ses that there's nothing else in the ideal. Therefore, $I$ is the ideal generated by $3$.

As for the quotient, one useful way to think about them is that $\text {"R/I is R, but with elements of I treated as 0"}$. In this case, the quotient is $\text {"$\mathbb {Z}$, but with multiples of 3 treated as $0$}"$. This should sound familiar!